# python parsing string \r\n new line

Tags: python, parsing, eval

i am having some problems with parsing lines.
Actually i have everything in one line like this:

```
'test:[abc:123];something\r\nName=some name;phone no.: [123456]\r\nAddress: some address; another   address\r\n\r\n'
```

i would like to have this line like this:

```
test:[abc:123];something
Name=some name;phone no.: [123456]
Address: some address; another address
```

i have tried with

```
#from ast import literal_eval
from ast import *
a = 'test:[abc:123];something\r\nName=some name;phone no.: [123456]\r\nAddress: some address; another address\r\n\r\n'
msg = literal_eval(a)
# and
msg = eval(a)
```

but i get error. Is there some other easy way to work this out?

Comment: Have you tried [`.split("\r\n")`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)?

Comment: Just an idea `a.split('\r\n')`

Comment: @jonrsharpe why? it seems to work :-p

Comment: @TimCastelijns see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinx_(children%27s_game). I'll take my Coca-cola at your convenience!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I didn't know about that game, I thought you meant my suggestion somehow brings bad luck ;-)

Comment: i have tried .split('\r\n') but i am not able to get each part in separate line

Comment: You can print these line separately as given in answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
kk = 'test:[abc:123];something\r\nName=some name;phone no.: [123456]\r\nAddress: some address; another address\r\n\r\n'
lk = "\n".join(kk.split("\r\n"))
print lk
```

**Output:**

```
test:[abc:123];something
Name=some name;phone no.: [123456]
Address: some address; another   address
```

Answer (score 1):

If this a string you've generated then try `.splitlines()` of `.split('\r\n')?`

If this is read from a file then try setting the line endings when you open the file.
Or open the file with `myfile = open(filename, 'r', newline='\n\r')`

Comment: Note that `file` is a builtin that although deprecated even in Python 2.x (and removed in Python 3) in preference of `open` - there's a remote possibly that shadowing it with a fileobj might well confuse things if `file` is meant to be used as the builtin function later.

Comment: @JonClements Thanks I changed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Split works fine:

```
    l = 'test:[abc:123];something\r\nName=some name;phone no.: [123456]\r\nAddress: some address; another   address\r\n\r\n'.split("\r\n")
    In [14]: for line in l:
   ....:         print line
   ....:     
    test:[abc:123];something
    Name=some name;phone no.: [123456]
    Address: some address; another   address
```